# Select Row by Username with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a Table with multiple users and the data belonging to them.
[image]

Now I want to create separate tables for each user like this:

[image]

Each account belonging to the users has a different ID so I can't use the ID to select.

How can I select the all Rows belonging to one specific name in the "User" row and then create separate table?

Also I would like take data out of a column and sort it into two new columns.

One example would be something like the email like:
John.tomson@email.com and split it at the dot and create two new Columns "Name" and "Surname".
[image]

Comment: Please include tables as text, not as images

Comment: wow, I copy pasted it into it from Pages (excel for Mac). No idea why its an image. I will copy it as text right away.

Comment: something like `for I,df_ in df.groupby('User'): df_.write_csv(f'{I}.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Breaking down by** `User`

```
df.groupby('User').get_group('John')
```

```
   ID  User                  Email
0   1  John  john.tomson@email.com
1   2  John  john.tomson@email.com
2   3  John  john.tomson@email.com
```

Can also be done in a loop

```
grp = df.groupby('User')

for group in grp.groups:
    print(grp.get_group(group))
```

```
                   Email  ID   User
3  david.matty@email.com   4  David
4  david.matty@email.com   5  David
                   Email  ID  User
5  fred.brainy@email.com   6  Fred
                   Email  ID  User
0  john.tomson@email.com   1  John
1  john.tomson@email.com   2  John
2  john.tomson@email.com   3  John
```

---

**Splitting the** `Email` **column**

```
email_df = df['Email'].str.split(r'(.+)\.(.+)@', expand=True)]
pd.concat([df, email_df], axis=1)
```

```
                   Email  ID   User      0       1          2
0  john.tomson@email.com   1   John   john  tomson  email.com
1  john.tomson@email.com   2   John   john  tomson  email.com
2  john.tomson@email.com   3   John   john  tomson  email.com
3  david.matty@email.com   4  David  david   matty  email.com
4  david.matty@email.com   5  David  david   matty  email.com
5  fred.brainy@email.com   6   Fred   fred  brainy  email.com
```

Comment: Awesome, so If I don't want to hardcode the Username I can just use a for loop to iterate over User and insert it into the .get_group{username}. Is that the cleanest way?

Comment: Yea, as an alternative to `.groups` you can get unique usernames by e.g. `df['User'].unique()`.

Comment: Very good explanation man! Thx so much. Can you write the whole statement please? so I can understand in what context to use df['User'].unique()